# Make Bootstrap divs responsive with Isotope

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Helllo everyone!

I'd really appreciate if someone could point me to the right direction.

I have this Tumblr page:

http://rhythmrepeattheme.tumblr.com/post/72323527332

Is there a way to make the columns responsive on resize?

`

```
$.Isotope.prototype._getMasonryGutterColumns = function() {
    var gutter = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.gutterWidth || 0;
    containerWidth = this.element.width();

    this.masonry.columnWidth = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.columnWidth ||
    // or use the size of the first item
    this.$filteredAtoms.outerWidth(true) ||
    // if there's no items, use size of container
    containerWidth;

    this.masonry.columnWidth += gutter;

    this.masonry.cols = Math.floor((containerWidth + gutter) / this.masonry.columnWidth);
    this.masonry.cols = Math.max(this.masonry.cols, 1);
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryReset = function() {
    // layout-specific props
    this.masonry = {};
    // FIXME shouldn't have to call this again
    this._getMasonryGutterColumns();
    var i = this.masonry.cols;
    this.masonry.colYs = [];
    while (i--) {
        this.masonry.colYs.push(0);
    }
};

$.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function() {
    var prevSegments = this.masonry.cols;
    // update cols/rows
    this._getMasonryGutterColumns();
    // return if updated cols/rows is not equal to previous
    return (this.masonry.cols !== prevSegments);
};

$( function() {

  var $container = $('.coniso');

  $container.isotope({
      resizable: true,
      isAnimated: true,
      masonry: {
      columnWidth: 100,
      gutterWidth: 0
    }
  });




});
```

`

Any help is appreciated.

Chaz

Comment: It seems responsive on the link. Can you provide some more information?